# Why is my button not being displayed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml, android-button

My button is set to size as needed (wrap_content); it *does* have a caption, yet it is invisible. It should be right below my ListView, I would think:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+android:id/listviewContacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical | horizontal" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSaveAndBegin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save_settings_and_begin_responding" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why is my button not being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default orientation for LinearLayout is horizontal. If you add android:orientation="vertical" to your LinearLayout then you should be all set.

Comment: Nice catch with the orientation.

Answer (score 3):

add vertical origination in your linear-layout like this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

and you don't need to add vertical scroll view property to the list view... Listview came with the default vertical scroll view

Answer (score 2):

Possibly because 300dip height is higher than the screen height?

Try lowering this and see if you can see it then

Comment: No, I can see the outline of the ListView covering about 2/3 of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
android:layout_height="300dip"
```

To this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

It is most likely a size problem, and this will make sure your view is the exact size of your screen.

Comment: What if I have a gazillion items in my list? Won't the ListView stretch all the way down to Australia, or even Tasmania, if I don't specify a height for it?

Comment: It will be as big as the parent... point is it's a test.. not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add button using ListView footer.